# What does FAST_FUNC do in busybox?

Tags: c, busybox

I found this while reading some code:

```
char* FAST_FUNC bb_simplify_path(const char *path)
```

Here `char*` is a return type, but I don't understand the role of `FAST_FUNC`. This `FAST_FUNC` is used in many places.

In general what does `FAST_FUNC` do in busybox?

Comment: Did you search the code for `#define FAST_FUNC`?

Answer (score 4):

From `include/platform.h`:

```
/* FAST_FUNC is a qualifier which (possibly) makes function call faster
 * and/or smaller by using modified ABI. It is usually only needed
 * on non-static, busybox internal functions. Recent versions of gcc
 * optimize statics automatically. FAST_FUNC on static is required
 * only if you need to match a function pointer's type */
#if __GNUC_PREREQ(3,0) && defined(i386) /* || defined(__x86_64__)? */
/* stdcall makes callee to pop arguments from stack, not caller */
# define FAST_FUNC __attribute__((regparm(3),stdcall))
/* #elif ... - add your favorite arch today! */
#else
# define FAST_FUNC
#endif
```

Basically, it activates an architecture-dependent function annotation that speeds up function calls. The actual annotation depends on the platform (hence the `#if`), but on x86/x86_64 (the only platforms currently implemented here), it activates "stdcall" calling conventions on the annotated function. `stdcall` enables some of the function's arguments to be passed in registers instead of the stack, which eliminates a few memory accesses from the function call calling sequence.

Comment: So you quote some arcane documentation in the source code. That's barely helpful. If you could translate that documentation into English so that we could understand it I'd reconsider. When does Busybox use this macro and why? Why not everywhere? Is there some drawback to using the macro?

Comment: That description is perfectly clear to me.  I didn't know what `regparm` was but assumed it meant to pass N arguments in registers and when I looked it up that is what it does.